# YouTrack Workflow Editor - How to Ask for Users Input

Tags: youtrack

When using the YouTrack Workflow Editor is it possible to ask the user for their input?  E.g. when the state of an issue is set to "Resolved" I want to effectively open the "Run Command" dialog box and let the user set how long they've spent on an the issue, for example.  Is this possible or can you only use the workflow editor to automatically set field values/send emails/present messages to the user?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Have a look at the jetbrains-youtrack-duplicates workflow, particulary the rule named 'When issue becomes duplicate it must have duplicate link'.

Comment: this seems to be changed - I can't find it. That's why *linking* or so in an answer is not recommend  [:-(

Comment: the workflow is now called @jetbrains/youtrack-workflow-duplicates. The rule's file is issue-in-duplicate-state-must-have-duplicates-link. The code is ctx.issue.required('duplicates', workflow.i18n('Add link to duplicate issue.')). Even if I did "the recommended" way the previous time, the code would not be working as the entire workflows functionality was changed to allow writing rules in pure JS.